# Clustering Markers from a KML file within openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, html

Is there a way to cluster markers within openlayers as there is within leaflet.

I have many markers which display the various listed buildings within wales and I am wondering if I am able to cluster them and then as a user zooms in the clusters get smaller until an individual marker is left.
And then on zoom out a the markers regroup/cluster showing a cluster with numbers on such as how many markers are within a set distance of lets say 10 miles or so?

Is there also a way to ensure that when a cluster size is at 1 it could show the `LSMarker` style being that of the original cross showed in the image below?

Link to current project so you can see what I mean by the need to cluster data:
https://ces-web2.southwales.ac.uk/students/18018815/mitchtut/giscw2/openlayer.htm

[image: Mobile chrome showing previous amount of markers]

**UPDATE 1 (THIS ISSUE HAS BEEN SOLVED)** 
Currently getting the error
current code

> Uncaught ha {message: "Assertion failed. See https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/doc/errors/#58 for details.", code: 58, name: "AssertionError"}

**UPDATE 2**
Error fixed but geo data not loading within correct area

Current code

```
var distance = document.getElementById('distance'); //getting the distance from the slider

<!-- var count = 1000; -->
<!-- var features = new Array(count); //creating an array to hold the amount of features for the cluster -->

<!-- var e = 4000; -->
<!-- for (var i = 0; i<count; i++){ -->
<!-- var coordinates = [2 * e * Math.random() - e, 2 * e * Math.random() - e]; -->
<!-- features [i] = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinates)); -->
<!-- } -->


    
var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
        distance: parseInt(distance.value,10),
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
                url: 'geoJSON/LSB.kml',
                format: new ol.format.KML({
                extractStyles:false,
            }),
        })
    });

var styleCache = {};

var clusters = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: clusterSource,
    style: function (feature) {
        var size = feature.get('features').length;
        var style = styleCache[size];
        if(!style) {
            style = new ol.style.Style ({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius:10,
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color:'#fff'
                    }),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        colo:'#3399CC'
                    })
                }),
                text: new ol.style.Text({
                    text: size.toString(),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color:'#fff'
                    })
                })
            });
            
            styleCache[size] = style;
        }
            return style;
    }
});

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source:new ol.source.OSM()
    });
    
distance.addEventListener('input', function(){
    clusterSource.setDistance(parseInt(distance.value));
});



//instantiation of the map within the div class 'mapspce'
var Omap = new ol.Map({
    layers:[raster, clusters],
    target:'mapspce',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform(cWales,'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 8
    })
});
```

Comment: Yes, place your KML source inside a cluster source as in https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/cluster.html

Comment: Thank you, tried adapting that but got some errors, could be because its late but thank you

Comment: The source for your `ol.source.Cluster` should be the `ol.source.Vector` for the KML not just its url.

Comment: @Mike I have included this within my code but the points locations are not loading in the correct geographic area now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clustering function now complete issue being that the KML coordinate data within the file is listed as

```
<MultiGeometry><Point><coordinates>-3.08246357229187,53.2285595916199</coordinates></Point></MultiGeometry>
```

With Multigeometry data not being picked up by leaflet as this must be a single point

```
//clustering 2 Eletricboogaloo
var distance = document.getElementById('distance');      

var Source = new ol.source.Vector({
            url:'geoJSON/LSB.KML',
            format: new ol.format.KML({
                extractStyles:false
        })
});

var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
    distance: parseInt(distance.value,10),
    source: Source
});

vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: clusterSource,
    style: LSMarker
});

var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source:new ol.source.OSM()
    });

//instantiation of the map within the div class 'mapspce'
var Omap = new ol.Map({
    layers:[raster, vector],
    target:'mapspce',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.transform(cWales,'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 8
    })
});

distance.addEventListener('input',function() {
    clusterSource.setDistance(parseInt(distance.value,10));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your KML source is not working with a cluster source it may contain features which are not Point geometry.  You can add a `geometryFunction` to the cluster source options to ensure only point features are used when  clustering:

```
var clusterSource = new ol.source.Cluster({
        distance: parseInt(distance.value,10),
        geometryFunction: function (feature) {
          var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
          if (geometry.getType() === "Point") {
            return geometry;
          } else if (geometry.getType() === "MultiPoint") {
            return geometry.getPoint(0);
          }
        },
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
                url: 'geoJSON/LSB.kml',
                format: new ol.format.KML({
                extractStyles:false,
            }),
        })
    });
```

Comment: The KML data does appear to be point data however , I cannot seem to get it to show even with your script, I can get it to work with random coordinate data but the data no longer appears to load, any chance of something missing?

Live Code here: https://ces-web2.southwales.ac.uk/students/18018815/mitchtut/giscw2/openlayer.htm

Comment: Could it be that the KML coordinate data within the file is listed like <MultiGeometry><Point><coordinates>-3.08246357229187,53.2285595916199</coordinates></Point></MultiGeometry>
is multigeometry the issue?

Comment: The error was to  do with the KML file, Its fixed, thank you for the help

Comment: A MultiGeometry consisting only of points would result in a MultiPoint geometry in OpenLayers, The geometry function could extract the point from that.  You can reduce any geometry to a point using `new ol.geom.Point(ol.extent.getCenter(feature.getGeometry().getExtent()))`